# window.parent.postMessage not working with scr="'data:text/html;charset=utf-8" in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to create small editor which allow user to edit the html using iframe. so passing html string into src as a data:text/html. but communication is not happening into parent window.

help me what i am doing wrong.

**index.html**

```html
<iframe id="creditMailBody"  class="iframe-main-content" src="{{creditMail.content}}"></iframe>
```

in html string

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="editor" contentEditable="true"></p>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log("input event fired");
    window.parent.postMessage('iframe_message', '*')
  }, false);
 </script>
</html>
```

in controller

```js
window.addEventListener('iframe_message', function() {
  console.log('iframe message')
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Typo:

The event is called `message`, not `iframe_message`:

```js
const frame_content = `<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="editor" contentEditable="true">edit me</p>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log("input event fired");
    window.parent.postMessage('iframe_message', '*')
  }, false);
 <\/script>
</html>`;
frame.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(frame_content);

window.addEventListener("message", function() {
                      //  ^-- Here it is "message"
  console.log('iframe message')
});
```

```html
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```